# Script command losing alias from shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, exec

When I run the script command it loses all the aliases from the existing shell which is not desired for people using lots of aliases. So, I am trying to see if I can automatically source the .profile again to see if it works without the user have to do it.

Here below is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
rm aliaspipe
mkfifo aliaspipe
bash -c "sleep 1;echo 'source ~/.bash_profile' > aliaspipe ;echo 'alias' > aliaspipe ;echo 'exec 0<&-' > aliaspipe"&
echo "starting script for recording"
script < aliaspipe
```

Basically I am creating a named pipe and the making the pipe as stdin to the script program, trying to run the source command and then close the stdin from pipe to the terminal stdin so that I can continue with the script.

But when I execute, the script is exiting after I execute "exec 0<&-",

```
bash-3.2$ exec 0<&-
bash-3.2$ exit

Script done, output file is typescript
```

Not sure why the exit is called and script is terminated. If I can make the script move the stdin from pipe to terminal then it should be fine.

Comment: `#!/bin/ksh` is not a bash script.  Perhaps you want `#!/bin/bash` instead?

Comment: I changed it , but still no luck :(

Comment: But is the target script you're running a bash script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get `script` to execute a `bash` login shell by telling it to do so explicitly.

```
# Gnu script (most Linux distros)
script -c "bash -l"
# BSD script (also Mac OS X)
script typescript bash -l
```

That will cause your `.bash_profile` to be sourced.

---

By the way, redirections are not stacks. When you write `exec 0<&-`, you're closing standard input, and when bash's standard input is closed, it exits.

Comment: In linux I don't see a problem but in OS X there is no -c option for script, any idea on how to make it work ?

Comment: @user1370642: According to the Mac OS X manpage, you would use `script typescript bash -l`, but I don't have a Mac handy to test it with.

Comment: @user1370642: Your question was tagged [tag:linux], which is generally considered a signal that you are looking for a linux solution.